# Kafka Consumer Cluster Environment Offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to have x number of consumers access a specified topic in kafka but not consume the same messages. I want for example...

Consumer 1 pick up offset 1
Consumer 2 pick up offset 2
Consumer 1 pick up offset 3
Consumer 2 pick up offset 4

I want kafka to act as a queue for those two consumers. I noticed the group.id configuration and I assumed that you could use the same group and it would handle it accordingly but it does not seem to work the way I thought it would.

Here is the code I am using...

```
     public void init(){
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaUrl);
            props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
            props.put("group.id", "group1");
            props.put("client.id", "KafkaConsumer-" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());

            consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("event1", "event2"));

            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(this::pollTopics, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }

     public void pollTopics() {
        try {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                AbstractProcessor processor = Processor.getProcessor(record.value(), record.topic(), mqttMapping, crudRepositoryStore);
                if(processor != null) {
                    kafkaThreadPool.execute(processor);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error("Polling exception occurred", e);
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to run this code in a cluster environment and have kafka be the queue. I want it to pull the message and go to the next offset at the same time, then the next kafka poll will grab the next offset. Is this possible? And if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in Kafka (in the way you describe it).

If you use consumer groups, a single partition can only be read by a single consumer. Thus, Kafka does scale by partitions, ie, if you want to have multiple consumers (reading different data) you need at least one partition for each consumer. If you have more partitions than consumers, some (or all) consumers will read multiple partitions at the same time.

The solution for you is, to create a topic with multiple partitions (or use multiple topics and let all consumers of your group subscribe to a topics).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I read that if you have 2 partitions you have to have at least 2 consumers. So what happens if one of the consumers goes down for a hour? The other consume will not pick up those messages right?

Comment: Wait, I think you do say that if there is 2 partitions and only one consumer that it will pick from both? So just to make sure I understand correctly. If I create two partitions and have two consumers it should parse different messages and if one does indeed go down then the other consumer will pick up all messages from both partitions? If this is correct do you have an example of what is needed to subscribe to specific partitions? If so then i will accept your answer :).

Comment: I also just read this paragraph from kafkas website.
"The consumer group concept in Kafka generalizes these two concepts. As with a queue the consumer group allows you to divide up processing over a collection of processes (the members of the consumer group). As with publish-subscribe, Kafka allows you to broadcast messages to multiple consumer groups."

This states that what I am trying to accomplish is possible. Just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Your second comment is correct. A consumer can read multiple topics. If you use group management and once consumer fails, the other takes over the failing consumer's partitions. You put different consumer into the same consumer group by specifying the same `group.id` in their configuration.

Comment: For the broadcasting case, you basically use different consumer groups as each group will read all partitions. If you only want to read a special partitions in a single consumer you need to to manual assignment that disables group management automatically. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008610/kafkaconsumer-0-10-java-api-error-message-no-current-assignment-for-partition/41010594#41010594

Comment: Awesome this is what I wanted. I managed to get it to work using the same group.id, I also read somewhere that they must be on different threads which might of been part of my issue. I tested on separate threads with the same group.id and it appears to load balance perfectly.