# KafkaConsumer 0.10 Java API error message: No current assignment for partition

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I am using KafkaConsumer 0.10 Java api. I want to consume from a specific partition and specific offset. I looked up and found that there is a seek method but its throwing an exception. Anyone had a similar use case or solution ?

Code:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("mytopic", 1), 4);
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition mytopic-1
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.seek(SubscriptionState.java:276)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1135)
    at xx.xxx.xxx.Test.main(Test.java:182)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Before you can `seek()` you first need to `subscribe()` to a topic ***or*** `assign()` partition of a topic to the consumer. Also keep in mind, that `subscribe()` and `assign()` are lazy -- thus, you also need to do a "dummy call" to `poll()` before you can use `seek()`.

> Note: as of Kafka 2.0, the new `poll(Duration timeout)` is async and it's not guaranteed that you have a complete assignment when `poll` returns. Thus, you might need to check your assignment before using `seek()` and also `poll` again to refresh the assignment. (Cf. [KIP-266](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-266%3A+Fix+consumer+indefinite+blocking+behavior) for details)

If you use `subscribe()`, you use group management: thus, you can start multiple consumers using the same `group.id` and all partitions of the topic will be assigned evenly over all consumers within the group automatically (each partition will get assigned to a single consumer in the group).

If you want to read specific partitions, you need to use manual assignment via `assign()`. This allows you to do any assignment you want.

Btw: `KafkaConsumer` has a very long an detailed class JavaDoc including examples. It's worth to read it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked :) with the combination of assign() and seek()

Comment: i think you mean `group.id` instead of `application.id`

Comment: Answering too many #KafkaStream questions here... Thanks for pointing out @automaticgiant

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  "Also keep in mind, that subscribe() and assign() are lazy -- thus, you also need to do a "dummy call" to poll() before you can use seek()." How the lazy type of subscribe and assign affects the the code? What if I don't use dummy poll like `poll(0)`?

Comment: I guess for assign() it's ok. But for `subscribe()` as long as you don't call `poll()` you did not join the consumer group and you don't have any partitions assigned. Thus, you will end up with an exception as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use **poll()** and retrieve map records, and change the offset itself. 
Kafka version 0.11
Try this:

```
...
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");    
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);    
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("Test_topic1", "Test_topic2"));
List<TopicPartition> partitions =consumer.partitionsFor("Test_topic1").stream().map(part->{TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(part.topic(),part.partition()); return tp;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
Field coordinatorField = consumer.getClass().getDeclaredField("coordinator"); 
coordinatorField.setAccessible(true);    

ConsumerCoordinator coordinator = (ConsumerCoordinator)coordinatorField.get(consumer);
coordinator.poll(new Date().getTime(), 1000);//Watch out for your local date and time settings
consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions); //or other seek
```

Poll for coordinator events. This ensures that the coordinator is known and that the consumer has joined the group (if it is using group management). This also handles periodic offset commits if they are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please use consumer.**assign** with consumer.**seek** and not consumer.**subscribe**

After these changes, it will execute fine.