# Apache kafka consumer poll infinite loop on unexpected messages

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm doing integration tests of Kafka consumer implementation.
I use wurstmeister/kafka docker image and Apache Kafka consumer.
The scenario that buzzes me is when I send "unexpected" messages to a topic. The `kafkaConsumer.poll(POLLING_TIMEOUT)` seems to go in an infinite loop in RUN mode. When I DEBUG though, it works when I pause and run back.

I don't have this issue when sending messages that are expected ( do not throw an exception on deserialization).

Here is my `docker-compose` configuration for kafka :

```
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  links:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "ProductLocation:1:1,ProductInformation:1:1,InventoryAvailableToSell:1:1"
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

The Java generic consumer :

```
@Override
public Collection<T> consume() {
    String eventToBePublishedName = ERROR_WHILE_RESETTING_OFFSET;
    boolean success = false;

    try {
        kafkaConsumer.resume(kafkaAssignments);
        if (isPollingTypeFull) {
            // dummy poll because its needed before resetting offset.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008610/kafkaconsumer-0-10-java-api-error-message-no-current-assignment-for-partition
            kafkaConsumer.poll(POLLING_TIMEOUT);
            resetOffset();
        } else if (!offsetGotResetFirstTime) {
            resetOffset();
            offsetGotResetFirstTime = true;
        }

        eventToBePublishedName = ERROR_WHILE_POLLING;

        ConsumerRecords<Object, T> records;

        List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            records = kafkaConsumer.poll(POLLING_TIMEOUT);
            records.forEach(cr -> {
                T val = cr.value();
                if (val != null) {
                    output.add(cr.value());
                }
            });
        } while (records.count() > 0);

        eventToBePublishedName = CONSUMING;
        success = true;
        kafkaConsumer.pause(kafkaAssignments);
        return output;
    } finally {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(
                new OperationResultApplicationEvent(
                        this, OperationType.ConsumingOfMessages, eventToBePublishedName, success));
    }
}
```

The deserializing :

```
public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
    try {
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(data);
        JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(getValueClass());
        JsonNode value = jsonNode.get("value");
        return mapper.readValue(value.toString(), javaType);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException | SerializationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Can't deserialize data [" + Arrays.toString(data)
                + "] from topic [" + topic + "]", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my integration tests, I create a topic for every test by sending to a time-stamped topic name. This creates new topics and makes tests stateless.

This is how I configure the Kafka consumer :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaConfiguration.getServer());
    properties.put("group.id", kafkaConfiguration.getGroupId());
    properties.put("key.deserializer", kafkaConfiguration.getKeyDeserializer().getName());
    properties.put("value.deserializer", kafkaConfiguration.getValueDeserializer().getName());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you face this, just `close` the consumers after using them, or `pause` after using and `resume` before starting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception and advance your committed offset by +1 to skip over the “poison pill” message.

Comment: Which exception are you talking about ?? I said that the poll goes on infinite loop. And it was because a previous consumer on that topic was not closed. Both use Kafka consumer which is not thread safe ==> Just closing the consumer fixed it. I just return null and then filter on the result of the consumer records polled as shown in the code sample. The offset is committed automatically.

Comment: I am talking about how to fix the previous consumer app. I though you said the previous consumer dies because it can’t deserialize an unexpected message. In that case you should fix that app to catch the SerDes exception (or any other exceptions) and either close and quit or advance offsets by 1 and continue.

Comment: The consumer doesn't die (thus doesn't throw an exception), it stays hanging during the poll. This is related to Apache kafka consumer thread safety. We need to close a kafka consumer for a specific topic and group id before creating a new one ( for same topic and group id ). That was the problem.