# Setting all partitions to their latest offset in Kafka but getting "No current assignment for partition"

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to set all my partitions to the latest offset in Kafka but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition idp-sanitizer-qa-test-8
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:256)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.requestOffsetReset(SubscriptionState.java:330)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(KafkaConsumer.java:1593)
    at com.company.data.process.sanitizer.e2eframework.kafka.Consumer.seekToEnd(Consumer.java:88)
    at com.company.data.process.sanitizer.e2eframework.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:43)
```

I want to set all partitions to their latest offset because I don't care about the data that has not yet been consumed. But I care about it when I am rerunning my program.

This is the method I am running to do so but I am getting the error above.

```
public void seekToEnd() {
        logger.info("Setting Kafka Consumer to latest offset...");
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfoList = this.kafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(this.topic);
        ArrayList<TopicPartition> partitions =  new ArrayList<>();
        for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : partitionInfoList) {
            partitions.add(new TopicPartition(this.topic, partitionInfo.partition()));
        }
        this.kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(partitions);
    }
```

In my constructor, I have already subscribed to a topic so `this.kafkaConsumer` should be subscribed to a topic

`this.kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));`

Comment: Deleted my reply, should be a comment as it was more or less replied here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008610/kafkaconsumer-0-10-java-api-error-message-no-current-assignment-for-partition

Comment: What you are lacking is a call to `poll` before you seek to end, you are not still "connected" if you are subscribing/assigning.